# Auto Refresh a Page at Specific Time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension, refresh

I am trying to add some code to a chrome extension, that will refresh a specific page at a certain time of the day. I've found coding that involves adding meta tags to the header, or tags to the body but I cant edit the page's html so this is not possible. This is the code I have of now but it doesnt seem to be working --

```
    //60000 milliseconds is 1 minute
window.setInterval("checkForRefresh()", 60000);

function checkForRefresh() {
   var now = new Date();
   if (now.getHours() == 14 && now.getMinutes() == 24) {
      window.location.reload();
   }
}
```

It seems to have worked a couple of times, but now it just stopped working. Not sure what went wrong.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Are you using a content-script for that ? Also, keep in mind that the user might be in the middle of doing something on the page when the refresh happens and it can be veeery annoying !

Comment: Yeah Im using the content script. The user wont be doing nothing at the time because they will be awaiting a timer countdown to finish and for it to be a certain time of day where they will need to refresh the page exactly at that time of day.

Comment: OK, then :) The solutions below should do the trick. BTW, if you want to develop an extension, you'll save a great deal of time by debugging easily resolved issues by yourself (instead of asking here). And when it comes to debugging an extension the Developer Console is your best friend !

Comment: Ok thanks, Im familiar with the developer console so I think now that I've injected the jquery it should show up.

Comment: You don't really need jQuery for this, but it won't hurt much either, I guess...

Comment: Did you try my proposed solution below ? Did it work for you ?

Answer (score 3):

Use `location.reload(true)`

That'll reload the page and bypass the cache, however, if you don't want to bypass the cache, set then use `location.reload(false)`

Take a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location#Example_.232.3A_Force_reloading_the_current_page_from_the_server).

Comment: It seems to work when using window.location.reload(false); but its refreshing a few seconds or milliseconds before the time I inputted

Comment: Ok I have to test some more cause it doesnt seem to be refreshing anymore. Not sure why

Answer (score 1):

`window.refresh()` is not a function. Try `window.location.reload()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

For a more reliable and resource friendly solution, you could use the **[`chrome.alarms` API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/alarms.html)** in a non-persistent background page (a.k.a. **[event page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html)**). E.g.:

**In *manifest.json*:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name":    "Test Extension",
    "version": "0.0",
    "offline_enabled": false,

    "background": {
        "persistent": false,
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },

    "permissions": [
        "alarms",
        "tabs"
    ]
}
```

**In *background.js*:**

```
var refreshAlarmName = 'refreshAlarm';

/* Refresh at: 10 Dec 2013, 22:11:00 UTC */
var utcYear    = 2013;
var utcMonth   = 11;   // <-- watch out: this is zero-based
var utcDate    = 10;
var utcHours   = 22;
var utcMinutes = 11;

/* Convert a date (year, month, dayOfMonth, hours, mins)
 * to milliseconds past the epoch */
function at(year, month, dayOfMonth, hours, mins) {
    var date = new Date();

    date.setUTCFullYear(year);
    date.setUTCMonth(month);
    date.setUTCDate(dayOfMonth);
    date.setUTCHours(hours);
    date.setUTCMinutes(mins);
    date.setUTCSeconds(0);
    date.setUTCMilliseconds(0);

    return date.getTime();
}

chrome.alarms.create(refreshAlarmName, {
    when: at(utcYear, utcMonth, utcDate, utcHours, utcMinutes)
});

chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function(alarm) {
    if (alarm.name !== refreshAlarmName) {
        return;
    }

    chrome.tabs.query({ url: "*://www.eastbay.com/*" }, function(tabs) {
        tabs.forEach(function(tab) {
            chrome.tabs.reload(tab.id, { bypassCache: true });
        });
    });
});
```

---

#### Important note:

According to the docs:

> *For performance reasons, the alarm may have been delayed an arbitrary amount beyond this.*

According to my experience, that *arbitrary amount* is hardly ever more than negligible, but if the exact timing is of the essence, you might want to consider a more sophisticated mechanism, where the background page fire's an alarm a couple of minutes before the target time, which injects a content script that sets a, say, 30secs interval to check for the target time and refresh.